# Question about referencing specific indexes in Terraform Interpolation

Tags: terraform

Let me first start out by saying that I currently have a working terraform configuration, however my IDE (VSCode; using the mauve.terraform extension, v 1.3.12) complains about my syntax when I do something like:

```
virtual_machine_name = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.sql["${count.index}"].name}"
```

It complains that it's expecting a '}' but found a '.'.

Should I be writing this out differently, or in a more "correct" manner? I'm fairly new to working with terraform so I'm sure my syntax could use some help.

Thanks in advance!

For reference, here's my full resource block:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "sql" {
  name                          = "OMSExtension"
  location                      = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.generics_sql_dev.location}"
  resource_group_name           = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.generics_sql_dev.name}"
  virtual_machine_name          = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.sql["${count.index}"].name}"
  publisher                     = "Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring"
  type                          = "MicrosoftMonitoringAgent"
  type_handler_version          = "1.0"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version    = true
  count                         = "${var.sql_node_count}"

  settings = <<-BASE_SETTINGS
  {
    "workspaceId" : "${data.azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.oms.workspace_id}"
  }
  BASE_SETTINGS

  protected_settings = <<-PROTECTED_SETTINGS
  {
    "workspaceKey" : "${data.azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.oms.primary_shared_key}"
  }
  PROTECTED_SETTINGS
}
```

Comment: It should be `"${azurerm_virtual_machine.sql.*.name[count.index]}"`

Comment: Thanks! That's got me squared away. Appreciate the help, and thanks for teaching me something new about the syntax!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Terraform 0.12 and later, the "standard" way to write that is:

```
  virtual_machine_name = azurerm_virtual_machine.sql[count.index].name
```

What you tried would also work in Terraform 0.12, but the string interpolations are redundant in that version. It works in Terraform 0.12 because of a special backward-compatibility rule that if a quoted string sequence consists *only* of a single interpolation (like `"${ ...anything ... }"`) then Terraform will ignore the quotes and just return the inner expression value directly.

That's only supported for backward-compatibility with configurations written for Terraform 0.11 and so I'd recommend avoiding it if you are using Terraform 0.12 or later; it tends to hurt readability by leaving a reader wondering if it implies conversion to a string.

---

For Terraform 0.11 and earlier, one level of string interpolation is required and indexing must be against a "splat operator":

```
  virtual_machine_name = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.sql.*.name[count.index]}"
```

The `azurerm_virtual_machine.sql.*.name` part here produces a list of `name` values, and then `[count.index]` selects one of them. This approach is required in Terraform 0.11 and earlier because in those versions the index operator `[...]` must always come at the *end* of a sequence of traversal steps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! This makes perfect sense. Seems like I was at least 'close' with my original interpretation. Glad to know the right way to do it for sure!

Comment: Just to completely close the loop here on this one, the original issue stems directly from the fact that the VSCode Extension "Terraform (mauve.terraform)" doesn't support 0.12 quite yet.

[link](https://github.com/mauve/vscode-terraform/issues/157) outlines the issue and there are a lot of folks trying to bring this functionality to the extension. 

Again, thanks to everyone for helping me understand the language a bit better. Your help has been very appreciated.